# Recursively searching for a property in object

Tags: javascript

I have an Object say `obj`.I need to search for a property `obj.property` if its not there(`undefined`) search in `obj.parent.property` .If its not there search in `obj.parent.parent.property` and so on.. until I get that property
like this..

```
obj.property                        [undefined]
obj.parent.property                 [undefined]
obj.parent.parent.property          [undefined]
obj.parent.parent.parent.property   [found] .Terminate here.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach by checking if the property exist, otherwise call `iter` again with the parent key.

```js
function iter(object) {
    return 'property' in object ? object.property : iter(object.parent);
}

var object = { parent: { parent: { parent: { parent: { property: 42 } } } } };

console.log(iter(object));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for...in` loop to crate recursive function that will search all nested objects for specified property and return its value.

```js
var obj = {lorem: {ipsum: {a: {c: 2}, b: 1}}}

function getProp(obj, prop) {
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (i == prop) return obj[i]
    if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
      var match = getProp(obj[i], prop);
      if (match) return match
    }
  }
}

console.log(getProp(obj, 'b'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recrusively check for the properties at each level. Check this answer:

[Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)